# Fancybox v2: Facebook Login Not Showing Up inside Fancybox

Tags: facebook, fancybox

is it possible to have a Facebook login button within the Fancybox AJAX popup?

I tried to program this but it just shows Login with Facebook without the actual button.

I have gotten Fancybox to call a HTML file which has:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="
        email,
        publish_stream
        ,user_education_history
        {*,user_birthday*}  {* Uncomment to enable *}
        ">
    Login with Facebook
  </div>
```

in it. And yet it doesn't show up within Fancybox.